# watson visual recognition pricing/costing clarifications

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

The documentation for the Watson Visual Recognition Services indicates that the costs for the service are

```
$0.25/Training image
$0.004 for classification per image per custom class
$10 for storage per custom class per month
```

So if I have 1 custom classifier with 1000 classes trained with 50 images each. Then the costs would be

```
$0.25 * 50000 = $12500 for initial training
$10 * 1000 = $10000 per month for storage
$4 per classification call if tested against all 1000 classes in the classifier
```

is my understanding correct? The $4 per call seems too high. Is the cost per class (1000 in this case) or per custom classifier (1 in this case)?

If I later add more training images (say additional 500 images), would the $0.25 per training image be charged for only these additional images ($0.25 * 500 = $125) or would it instead be $0.25 * 50500 = $12625?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question for IBM Bluemix Support. You can open a support ticket at https://support.ng.bluemix.net/technicalsupport/. Stack Overflow is for technical programming questions.

Comment: Thanks @ralphearle. I have raised a ticket.